# Cocos2dx - Compiling for android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

**** Build of configuration Default for project HelloCpp ****

```
bash C:/Development/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/build_native.sh 
cygwin warning:
MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Development\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android
Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Development/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android
CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
NDK_ROOT = C:\Development\ndk;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Development\ndk;C:\cygwin64\bin
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/Development/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../..
APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/Development/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/Development/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
+ 'C:\Development\ndk;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Development\ndk;C:\cygwin64\bin/ndk-build' -C /cygdrive/c/Development/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android NDK_MODULE_PATH=/cygdrive/c/Development/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../..:/cygdrive/c/Development/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
C:/Development/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/build_native.sh: line 90: **C:\Development\ndk;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Development\ndk;C:\cygwin64\bin/ndk-build: No such file or directory
```

** Build Finished **

[image]

I'm not sure why this is giving me this error. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to that problem, I had edited the NDK_ROOT inside the eclipse project. Like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFDlc.png

That's why it was giving that weird path in NDK_ROOT, now i don't have that problem anymore. But the app is not running on my phone thought. Whenever i try to install it it says "App not installed".